# Microsoft Access hide 0 from field

Tags: ms-access, formatting

In Access reports, I am able to hide the fields with 0 with the Textbox Format in the Property Sheet with this:

0;;"";

The code above will hide all the zeroes from all the fields in that column. However, without using the semi-colons, (actually only using a single character), is it possible to do the same as the code above?

Comment: If that works, why not use it? That is, what is the problem with the solution above you are trying to solve.

Comment: well i forgot to add a tag homework, but we need to use only 1 character to do it, we cant use semi colons even though we can (we just cant for this question)

Comment: Can you cite the exact wording of what your teacher is asking for? From the way you have described it, the requirement seems somewhat nonsensical.

Comment: While a Custom Format can have up to four sections - separated by semicolons(;) - only a single section is needed in this particular case. In fact, only a single section containing a single character is needed here, i.e. no semicolons.

Comment: What is "This particular case" referring to?

Comment: For each medal-winner, the number of gold, silver and bronze medals won is displayed, as in Part A. But now, when the number is zero, a blank space is shown instead.

Comment: What happens if you leave off everything after the first character in your formatting string....?

Comment: nothing lol its exactly the same

Comment: @Bart was not aware of that. Sorry, old habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you are looking for is hash: #

Read [Format Property - Number and Currency Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa159672%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for more information. For the most part, check MSDN. The Office articles seem to have got worse and worse.